# How to make my program output binaries in reverse

Tags: java

My assignment is to output decimals to binaries. An example would be inputting 100 and then the binary output would be 1100100.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dec2Bin {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Welcome to Decimal Number to Binary Converter");
        System.out.println("");

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a decimal number (-1 to end):");
        int input = s.nextInt();

        for ( ; ; ){
            if (input < 0)
                break;

            String bi = "";

            while(input != 0){
                bi = ((input % 2) + bi);
                input = input / 2;
            }
            System.out.println("The binary number is:" + bi);
        }
    }
}
```

Right now my program gets stuck in an infinite loop and the binary number prints out to be 0010011. I cannot figure out how to stop the infinite loop and reverse my binary number so it is correct.

Comment: Downvoting a new user without leaving a comment is not so friendly.

Comment: Hints: (1) If you want to set up a loop to let the user input multiple values, it helps for the input statement to be inside the loop rather than outside.  (2) A simple tweak to the statement that builds up `bi` will solve the other problem--think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your loop is running forever is because your break condition

```
 if (input < 0)
            break;
```

Will never be true. If you keep diving an integer by 2, it will converge to 0; however, 0 divided by 2 is still 0, so the integer will never fall below 0.

Consider changing the loop to this:

```
while(input > 0) {
    // code here
}
```

This way, the loop will end when input is 0. You also won't need the inner `while` loop.

Although there are methods to actually build the binary number in the correct sequence, that is not your question. To see why it is building in reverse, just use your test case and trace the program:

```
--- input = 100
100 % 2 == 0;
bi = 0;
--- input = 50
50 % 2 == 0;
bi = 00;
--- input = 25
25 % 2 == 1;
bi = 001;
--- and so on
```

To reverse your string when the number is converted, either make your own function (should be relatively simple), or use a handy `StringBuilder` method like so:

```
String biReverse = new StringBuilder(bi).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: When I add the int biReverse to my program, it tells me that i cannot convert a string into an integer. What could be causing this?

Comment: Oh ok, I added it in right before my final System.out.println("The binary number is" + biReverse); and the program still doesn't print it in reverse, it outputs 0010011

Comment: What happens when you just print `bi`, then? Also, I don't know exactly what you're doing, but the print statement needs to be outside of the while loop, but inside the infinite loop.

Comment: Oh, for some reason it prints 1100100 now... I have no idea how that happened.

Comment: Well, at least you know it works now! (:
Check this as the answer, too!

Answer (score 0):

The following condition is the cause for your infinite loop.

```
if (input < 0)
    break;
```

If you keep dividing, the answer won't go below zero/negative. It should be:

```
if (input == 0)
    break;
```

(This condition can be modified into the for loop). Otherwise your program works. I'm not getting the response in reverse...

Also, to make it a proper menu-driven program, you'll again need to change the condition & put the `int input = s.nextInt();` inside the for loop.